# ¿ cómo crear una tabla en postgresql e insertar datos a partir de un excel file?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, csv

Tengo registros en una planilla excel, dichos registros debo cargarlos en una tabla postgresql, al construir los insert (cadena), el campo fecha más hora los convierto a texto. Generado los insert la columna hora fecha, queda de la forma siguiente:

```
Insert EXCEL: =+CONCATENAR("INSERT INTO tab_origen(id_contrato,sentido,gps_imei,ppu,gps_fecha_hora,gps_direccion,gps_latitud,gps_longitud,nombre_archivo_carga) VALUES ('",A3,"',",B2,",",C2,",'",D2,"',","'"&TEXTO(E2,"dd-mm-aaaa HH:MM:SS")&"'",",",F2,",",G2,",",H2,",'",I2,"')")&";"

Salida INSERT: INSERT INTO tab_origen(id_contrato,sentido,gps_imei,ppu,gps_fecha_hora,gps_direccion,gps_latitud,gps_longitud,nombre_archivo_carga) VALUES ('CTA0472',NULL,NULL,'KRPS16','01-07-2020 09:42:00',0,-37814945,-72684254,'MTT_CTA0472_202007');
```

Como podrán ver la salida la columna fecha hora quedo como: '01-07-2020 09:42:00'. Al ejecutar la carga en la base de datos postgresql, la columna fecha hora, me trunca la fecha y solo me carga la hora, cabe señalar que la columna en la base de datos esta definida como time with time zone. Acá como queda el registro en la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Convierte tu archivo excel a formato cvs, y utiliza COPY para poder hacer ese proceso. Aquí hay un excelente tutorial que te puede ayudar https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/

Ejemplo:

```
COPY table_example(att1, att2, att3, att4)
FROM '/home/my/data/table_example.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Puedes también utilizar pgadmin4 e importarlo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]